# How do I get modals working for more than one image in a website gallery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have learned how to make an image open in a modal when a thumbnail is clicked, but what I am having trouble with is getting it working for multiple thumbnails on a page. Here is an example, with only 3 images but eventually I will have  a lot more than 3. I am getting a console error of TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(img)') I want to be able to have a gallery of images, you click on any of them, the modal pops up, you click on the x or the background and the modal closes. I can do this for a single image and I can do it for several images with a separate script for each but only the last one can be closed. I am trying to find some way of doing it for an array, so it works for all the images on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <style>

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg_001, #myImg_002, #myImg_003 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg_001:hover, #myImg_002:hover, #myImg_003:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
            
            /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
            
/* The Close Button */               
#close_001, #close_002, #close_003 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#close_001:hover, #close_002:hover, #close_003:hover,
#close_001:focus, #close_002:focus, #close_003:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#caption_001, #caption_002, #caption_003 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
            
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <img id="myImg_001" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <img id="myImg_002" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        <img id="myImg_003" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        
        <div id="myModal_001" class="modal">
            <span id="close_001">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_001">
            <div id="caption_001" ></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="myModal_002" class="modal">
            <span id="close_002">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_002">
            <div id="caption_002" ></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal_003" class="modal">
            <span id="close_003">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_003">
        <div id="caption_003" ></div>
        </div>
      
<script>
    
var myImgArray = [ 'myImg_001', 'myImg_002', 'myImg_003' ];
                  
var myModalArray = [ 'myModal_001', 'myModal_002', 'myModal_003' ];
    
var imgIdArray = [ 'img_001', 'img_002', 'img_003' ];
    
var captionArray = [ 'caption_001', 'caption_002', 'caption_003' ];
    
var closeArray = [ 'close_001', 'close_002', 'close_003' ];

function modalFunction(index, value) { 
        // Get the modal
        var modal = myModalArray[i];
        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = myImgArray[i];
        var modalImg = imgIdArray[i];
        var captionText = captionArray[i];
        var close = closeArray[i];
        document.getElementById(img).onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(modalImg).src = this.src;
        document.getElementById(captionText).innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
document.getElementById(close).onclick = function() { document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "none"; }
window.onclick = function(event) { if (event.target == document.getElementById(modal)) { document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "none"; } }
    }    
    
myModalArray.forEach(modalFunction);    
        

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you've solved the issue, don't include it as part of your question - instead, roll back your last edit post it as a self-answer below. It makes it much easier for others to discern what the issue *was* and how *exactly* you were able to correct it.

Comment: I have now got this working. My main issue was incorrect use of forEach, and it now works after I switched to a traditional for loop.

Comment: @synthetick provided an answer that makes you code a little cleaner.

Comment: @DavidKerr Thanks so much for your suggestions. I found that when I was using classes it didn't work, and I had to switch to everything having a separate id

Comment: @synthetick no worries :) -- there's an example of how to use classes and cut down on repetition. Less code to maintain if you want to add an image. You don't need an id for every close, modal, image, imgId and caption.  If you need any more help just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store so many variables or create individual modals for each image.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".body__image");
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

const toggleModal = (image) => {
  const modal = document.querySelector(`#modal`);
  modal.classList.toggle("hidden");

  if (image) {
    const modalImage = modal.querySelector("img");
    modalImage.src = image.src;
    const modalCaption = modal.querySelector("#caption");
    modalCaption.innerHTML = image.alt;
  }
};

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    toggleModal(image);
  });
});

closeButtons.forEach((closeButton) => {
  closeButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    toggleModal();
  });
});
```

```css
 /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.body__image {
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.body__image:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Modal Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <img
      class="body__image"
      id="myImg_001"
      src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg"
      alt="Image 1"
    />
    <img
      class="body__image"
      id="myImg_002"
      src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg"
      alt="Image 2"
    />
    <img
      class="body__image"
      id="myImg_003"
      src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg"
      alt="Image 3"
    />

    <div id="modal" class="modal hidden">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" />
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now got this working. My main issue was incorrect use of forEach, and it now works after I switched to a traditional for loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <style>

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg_001, #myImg_002, #myImg_003 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg_001:hover, #myImg_002:hover, #myImg_003:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
            
            /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
            
#close_001, #close_002, #close_003 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#close_001:hover, #close_002:hover, #close_003:hover,
#close_001:focus, #close_002:focus, #close_003:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#caption_001, #caption_002, #caption_003 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
            
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <img id="myImg_001" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <img id="myImg_002" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        <img id="myImg_003" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        
        <div id="myModal_001" class="modal">
            <span id="close_001">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_001">
            <div id="caption_001" ></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="myModal_002" class="modal">
            <span id="close_002">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_002">
            <div id="caption_002" ></div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal_003" class="modal">
            <span id="close_003">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img_003">
        <div id="caption_003" ></div>
        </div>
      
<script>
    
var myImgArray = [ 'myImg_001', 'myImg_002', 'myImg_003' ];
                  
var myModalArray = [ 'myModal_001', 'myModal_002', 'myModal_003' ];
    
var imgIdArray = [ 'img_001', 'img_002', 'img_003' ];
    
var captionArray = [ 'caption_001', 'caption_002', 'caption_003' ];
    
var closeArray = [ 'close_001', 'close_002', 'close_003' ];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        var modal = myModalArray[i];
        var img = myImgArray[i];
        var modalImg = imgIdArray[i];
        var captionText = captionArray[i];
        var close = closeArray[i];
        document.getElementById(img).onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(modalImg).src = this.src;
        document.getElementById(captionText).innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
document.getElementById(close).onclick = function() { document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "none"; }
window.onclick = function(event) { if (event.target == document.getElementById(modal)) { document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "none"; } }
    }    
    
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```